# Getting SqlLiteException when creating Db Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting error when trying to create a db using SqlLite.

This is the error code

```
07-04 03:50:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(786): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timetable ( id INTEGER PRIMARY , day INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  sub_id INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  time_from TEXT NOT NULL ,  time_to TEXT NOT NULL )
```

cant figure out why this error is coming

This is the Code which creates the Db:

```
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timetable ( id INTEGER PRIMARY , day INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  sub_id INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  time_from TEXT NOT NULL ,  time_to TEXT NOT NULL )");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS noofperiods (  id INTEGER PRIMARY ,  noofperiod INTEGER NOT NULL )");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS timetable");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS noofperiods");
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `KEY` word after `PRIMARY` :

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timetable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, day INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  sub_id INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  time_from TEXT NOT NULL ,  time_to TEXT NOT NULL )");
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS noofperiods (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  noofperiod INTEGER NOT NULL )");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `PRIMARY` to `PRIMARY KEY`.so
try

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timetable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, day INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  sub_id INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  time_from TEXT NOT NULL ,  time_to TEXT NOT NULL )");
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS noofperiods (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  noofperiod INTEGER NOT NULL )");
```

instead of

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timetable ( id INTEGER PRIMARY , day INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  sub_id INTEGER  NOT NULL ,  time_from TEXT NOT NULL ,  time_to TEXT NOT NULL )");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS noofperiods (  id INTEGER PRIMARY ,  noofperiod INTEGER NOT NULL )");
```